# How to add abline, without so much programming?

Tags: r

Do you know if there is a way to reduce the programming lines.

```
abline(v = c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994, 1995,1996,
             1997,1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,
             2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,
             2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017),
col = c("red","red","red","red","red","red","red",
        "red","red","red","red","red","red","red",
        "red","red","red","red","red","red","red",
        "red","red","red","red","red","red","red"), 
lty = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
       2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
lwd = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
h = c(200,400,600,800,1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
abline(v = seq(1990, 2017, 1),
       col = rep("red", 28),
       lty = rep(2, 28),
       lwd = rep(1, 28),
       h = seq(200, 1000, 200))
```

Comment: No need for `rep("red", 28)` - just specify `"red"` and R will recycle. Same for the other variables too. Like `abline(v = seq(1990, 2017, by=1), h = seq(200, 1000, by=200), col="red", lty=2, lwd=1)`

Comment: Could also use `v = 1990:2017`.

Comment: Both excellent points - thank you thelatemail and neilfws! - so the most concise way appears to be `abline(v = 1990:2017, col = "red", lty = 2, lwd = 1, h = seq(200, 1000, 200))`